# Algorithm notation

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, consensus

I am reading Nancy Lynch's Distributed Algorithms.

In page 103, there is the FloodSet algorithm.
Can anyone please explain what Uj mean in W := W U Uj xj  (line 3 of transition function)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*⋃* is the *n-ary union* operator, similar to how *∑* is the *n-ary addition* operator.

So, in the same way that *∑<sub>j</sub> someExpressionDependingOnJ* means "add the values of all the different instances of *someExpressionDependingOnJ* ranging over all *j*s together", *⋃<sub>j</sub> someExpressionDependingOnJ* means "union the values of all the different instances of *someExpressionDependingOnJ* ranging over all *j*s together".

*X* here is the dictionary of all messages indexed by the message sender, *X<sub>j</sub>* is the message from sender *j* in the dictionary.

Putting all of that together, *⋃<sub>j</sub> X<sub>j</sub>* is the union of all messages.

Comment: I guess the "double union" (result of large union of X_j being united with W) is the confusing part.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly suitable is also to bring general formal definition of union with respect to  [indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family):

Suppose we have set $X$, called indices set, and for each $\alpha \in X$ is defined some $U_\alpha$ set. Then, by definition, set
$$\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in X}U_\alpha=\{x\colon \exists \alpha \in X, x\in U_\alpha\}$$
is called union with respect to  indexed family $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in X}$. If, for example, we take $X=\{1,2\}$, then we obtain usual union of two sets. For $X=\{1, \cdots, n\}$ it is union with respect to $n$ sets asked OP.